# Jenkins: Unable to connect to the server. executable aws not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, kubernetes

I run Jenkins on OS X and at one step, I receive the following error,

```
Constructing AWS CredentialsSetting AWS region us-east-1a 
 [Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo 'Deploy blue container...'
Deploy blue container...
[Pipeline] sh
+ /usr/local/bin/kubectl apply -f ./blue/blue.yaml
Unable to connect to the server: getting credentials: exec: executable aws not found

It looks like you are trying to use a client-go credential plugin that is not installed.

To learn more about this feature, consult the documentation available at:
      https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins
```

The error informs that executable AWS not found. How do I provide it to the Jenkins?

PS:

```
$ aws --version 
aws-cli/2.2.3 Python/3.8.8 Darwin/19.6.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

Comment: did you export the AWS credentials as environment variables or something like that? what about kubeconfig? would be helpful if you would add the Jenkins config of that part.

Comment: Have you tried `brew install awscli`?

Comment: @jordanm The awscli was not installed, so I will install it and try again to see if this works out.

Comment: @JuanFontes What I can do about the Kubeconfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I delete the minikube and started again. After that this is fine:

```
minukube delete
minukube start
```